# Variable callback entrypoint in smartpy

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

Is it possible to use a variable as the `entry_point` for a callback in smartpy?

This works:

```
    @sp.entry_point
    def getProofs(self, address, callback_address):
        c = sp.contract(TGetProofsResponsePayload, callback_address, entry_point="getProofsCallback").open_some()
        sp.transfer(sp.record(address=address, proofs=self.data.identities[address]), sp.mutez(0), c)
```

This does not:

```
    @sp.entry_point
    def getProofs(self, address, callback_address, callback_entrypoint):
        c = sp.contract(TGetProofsResponsePayload, callback_address, entry_point=callback_entrypoint).open_some()
        sp.transfer(sp.record(address=address, proofs=self.data.identities[address]), sp.mutez(0), c)
```

Getting the following error:

```
Error: Error in Scenario
Expression format error (a 4) (contract (attr (params 64) callback_entrypoint 170)
(record
((address address) (callback_entrypoint string)
(proofs
(map string
(record
((meta (map string string)) (register_date timestamp) (verified bool))
None))))
None)
(attr (params 64) callback_address 170) 68)
```

Any ideas? ‍♂️

I guess I can pass a `routing_key` or `callback_id` to handle different scenarios for the callback, but seems cleaner not to force the callback entrypoint name?

Thanks ❤️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `callback_address` can be `tz1...%getProofsCallback`.

The smartpy code would then look like:

```
c = sp.contract(TGetProofsResponsePayload, callback_address).open_some()
```

The CONTRACT instruction `CONTRACT %name t` has annotation as you can see and those cannot be dynamic.

To get the address with entry_point information you can do:

```
# when building the callback
callback_address = sp.self_entry_point(entry_point = 'getProofsCallback')
```

Comment: Added an example on how to build the callback with entrypoint information

Comment: Fantastic  Works like charm  I had to use `sp.self_entry_point_address` to get what I needed, but yeah... thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there any functions to build such a callback_address from a testcase?  Would like to make a test to verify that contract X cannot trigger unwanted behaviour on contract A via calling getProofs on contract B  (getProofs is on B and getProofsCallback is on A in this case)

Comment: Yes. You can do the following: https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmRQ3CpLToZwGVJaNt2W4JfZNu7sUWP9NB7F7MsV464bj7&k=2413bede71ec97c875a5